# How to Turn <This Bookmarklet> into a Form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bookmarklet

Can anyone help me doing this? I want to turn this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:try{s1=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.toString();s2=escape(s1.substr(s1.indexOf('flashvars.un'),128)+s1.substr(s1.indexOf('flashvars.title'), 128));location.href='http://somesite.something.com/index.html?input='+s2;}catch(err){location.href='http://somesite.something.com/index.html';}
```

into a form, in a way that, the user inputs an URL and then click submit to "activate" bookmarklet's function in the same webpage the form is placed. I asked to a few people, but all they say is that "it is tricky" to do... Can anyone do it? I need this to be done and I'm kinda lost here,

Thank you guys ;)

P.S. Any kind of advice or HowTo will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a form, where users enter a url of a page that has a flash movie. Then some process extracts the flash and opens it fullscreen.
That is not possible unless you write a server process since a bookmarklet runs in the scope of the page you are on and the form on pageA cannot execute a script in the scope of pageB

If you use HTA (html application) you COULD extract something from an iframe

Comment: So, it's not possible to do? amm and if I try to use Prompt would it be possible?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Can you elaborate on exactly what you want to happen?

Comment: It is simple, I want to Turn That bookmarklet into a Form in order to let the users input a URL and then click a button to get the bookmarklet's function to work... If it's not possible, I was wondering if I can use "prompt" inside that bookmarklet in order to let the user input a URL and then activate Bookmarklet's function.

Comment: The bookmarklet works from the locationbar of a page that already has a flash on it. You cannot put a form on another page and have some client side javascript extact a flash from ANOTHER page on abnother domain. On the same domain as the form, yes, but that is not interesting.